# Unknown database type enum requested Doctrine orm Silex

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

When using Silex with [dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider) I've got the error message when trying to run orm:convert-mapping :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException' with message 'Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.'
```

Doctrine didn't manage enum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `$app->register(new Dflydev\Silex\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider(), array(...`

just register a new TypeMapping :

```
$app['orm.em']->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

It will solve the issue.